# spin_lock before writing status register

Tags: linux-kernel, synchronization, spinlock

I'm looking at linux driver where I see this:

```
spin_lock_bh(&driver->xy_lock);

/* code to clear a status bit from 32 bit PCI register */

iowrite32(...);

spin_unlock_bh(&driver->xy_lock);
```

Isn't this unnecessary to obtain a lock to clear a status bit? If not, why?

Comment: That depends on the behaviour of the code itself, the hardware, and any other code accessing the same hardware.

Comment: does the comment represent code that reads a value, and subsequently clears the bit, or are you saying that happens only due to the iowrite32 call?